# How was Astrid's Master treated poorly?

Tags: atelier

In *Atelier Rorona: Alchemist of Arland*, it's revealed the reason way Astrid never helped the people of Arland was because her Master was treated poorly, so Astrid decided, as a from of revenge, not help them.

I am wondering what Astrid means by her master was treated poorly. was she just ignored or was she never given appreciation for her work or did the people see Alchemy poorly and thus saw her master poorly?